# App configuration azure terraform replica block giving error

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-app-configuration

I am writing terraform config for azure app configuration block
everything is working fine except replica block when I comment that replica block code is running without any issues.

Tried multiple options but still error is same.

Comment: unsupported block type is the error for replica block

Comment: please share the code you tried along with error you're facing

Comment: replica {
       name     = var.app_config_replica_name
       location = var.app_config_replica_location
   }

Comment: Hello Vinay ,Sorry but I can not share full code due to policy

Comment: At least we need the module causing the blocker along with the error info will work @Ganesh

Comment: Please share the version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to provision the App configuration Azure terraform replica block and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The Blocker mentioned in the comments **unsupported block type is the error for replica block** represents the depreciation of the provider info.

The replica block was introduced in the app_configuration terraform [module](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/22452) from the [version](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases?page=2)  **3.74.0**. To use this module in your configuration make sure you updated the provider version equal or greater than **3.74.0**.

when you uncomment the module replica with the version mentioned you will be able to achieve the requirement you're looking for.

I took the demo Terraform configuration to check replica blocks work fine with the updated provider version.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    app_configuration {
      purge_soft_delete_on_destroy = true
      recover_soft_deleted         = true
    }
  }
}  # For reference purposes I was using the latest version of provider 3.84.0 (Latest)

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovk-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-identity"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                       = "demovkKVt123"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "standard"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7
  purge_protection_enabled   = true
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "server" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.principal_id

  key_permissions    = ["Get", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get"]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "client" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions    = ["Get", "Create", "Delete", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify", "GetRotationPolicy"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get"]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "demovkKVkey"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048
  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey"
  ]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.server,
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "example" {
  name                       = "appConf2vk"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                        = "standard"
  local_auth_enabled         = true
  public_network_access      = "Enabled"
  purge_protection_enabled   = false
  soft_delete_retention_days = 1

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [
      azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id,
    ]
  }

  encryption {
    key_vault_key_identifier = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id
    identity_client_id       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.client_id
  }

  replica {
    name     = "replica1"
    location = "West US"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "development"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.server,
  ]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Vinay Thanks for your reply , Earlier I was using tf version 3.65 now I changed it to 3.82 and it is working fine